# OpenGL screen space motion blur

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to implement post process motion vector based motion blur.
It kinda "works"...

I am experiencing 2 major issues with it:

1. If neither the object nor camera move the drawing produces empty
   screen.
2. There are distortions of the object along the borders of the screen.

This is 2 pass approach: pass#1 -rendering the object into FBO texture.pass#2 - rendering to full screen quad and applying MB to the previous pass output.

**Vertex shader for the second pass:**

```
void main(void){
    // transform previous and current position to eye space
    vec4 P =     MODEL_VIEW_MATRIX * position;
    vec4 Pprev = prevModelView * position;
    vec3 motionVector = P.xyz - Pprev.xyz;

    // calculate window space motion vector
    P =           PROJ  * MODEL_VIEW_MATRIX * position;
    Pprev =       PROJ * prevModelView * position;
    Pprev = mix(P, Pprev, blurScale);

    // choose previous or current position based on dot product between motion vector 
    // and normal
    vec3 N = mat3(MODEL_VIEW_MATRIX) *normal;
    bool flag = dot(motionVector, N) > 0;
    vec4 Pstretch = flag ? P : Pprev;
    gl_Position =  position;

    // do divide by W -> NDC coordinates
    P.xyz = P.xyz / P.w;
    Pprev.xyz = Pprev.xyz / Pprev.w;

    // calculate window space velocity
    vec3 dP = (P.xyz - Pprev.xyz) * halfWindowSize.xyz;
    float len = length (dP)/(halfWindowSize[0]*2);
    len = clamp(len, 0., 1.);
    dP =  normalize(dP);
    dP.z = len; 
    out_velocity = dP;
}
```

**Fragment shader for the second pass:**

```
void main(void){
    float w = 1.0 / samples;        
    vec4 a=vec4(0.);
    vec2 velocity = out_velocity.xy * blurScale * .05 * out_velocity.z;

    ivec2 tsize = textureSize(COLOR_MAP_0, 0);
    vec2 screntc = gl_FragCoord.xy * (1.0 / vec2(tsize));

    // sample into scene texture along motion vector 
    for(float i=0; i<samples; i+=1) 
    {
        float t = i / (samples-1);
        a = a + texture(COLOR_MAP_0, vec2(screntc)  + velocity * t ) * w;               
    }

    colorOut = a;
 }
```

What is wrong in these shaders?

Comment: *"What is wrong in these shaders?"* - They are awfully formatted. ;)

Comment: Yeah,I still have to learn using SO... ;)

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?

Comment: @genpfault that is not a problem here.I use # version 420 core

Comment: What is an "empty screen"? A black one or nothing written? Maybe some more code might also help, like some applciation code or the other shaders and the rest of the shader code (ins, outs, uniforms)...

Comment: Well,this question is so old I even don't remember how I solved it.But eventually I went with accumulative MB.

Comment: @MichaelIV *"I even don't remember how I solved it."* - Well, in this case you should have probably answered the question right after you solved it when you still knew it. Now we got an abandoned question worth plain nothing.

Comment: I will take care of it.